# MySQL no longer starts (but it used to) on xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

mySQL won't start and it throws up this in the log: http://pastebin.com/rTvMiQFV.

This seems quite common on here, but none of the solutions I've read have worked.

The only difference I can see between my problem and everyone else's is that mine has only just started happening, I was using it just fine before and it stopped at random after I restarted my computer.

It's happened before, and after trying everything I ended up backing up my databases and reinstalling the whole of xampp, but I don't really want to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try doing the suggested steps:

```
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This question is actually 2 months old, I did try that to no avail and ended up backing up my databases and reinstalling the whole of xampp.